# ¿Es posible mostrar unos datos determinados?

Tags: jsf, xhtml

En el código que voy a dejar muestro todos los registros de la tabla oferta, ahora bien, ¿es posible mostrar solo las ofertas de registradas en un día determinado por ejemplo?. Había pensado en hacer otra tabla con esos datos registrados y mostrar los registros de dicha tabla, pero tal vez sea posible mostralos a través de una misma tabla. Dejo el código:

```
<body>

    <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/Template.xhtml">

         <ui:define name="content">
            <h:outputText value="Total de ofertas:#{ofertasFacadeREST.countREST()}
          "/>
```

```
<h:form>
    <h1><h:outputText value="Lista de ofertas disponibles"/></h1>

    <p:dataTable value="#{ofertasFacadeREST.findAll()}" var="item">
         <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Id"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Nombre"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.nombre}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Descripción"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.descripcion}"/>
        </p:column>

         <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Fecha de incorporación"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.fecha_Insc}"/>
        </p:column>

          <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Puesto de trabajo"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.puesto}"/>
        </p:column>



          <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Requisitos"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.requisitos}"/>
        </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, es posible. Primefaces te provee formas de filtrar, con algoritmos ya provistos por el Framework o permitiéndote crear un `filter custom`.

Para tu caso podrías crearte un método en tu backing bean para poder filtrar las ofertas.

```
<p:column filterFunction="#{tuBackingBean.filtrarPorFecha}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Fecha de incorporación"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.fecha_Insc}"/>
</p:column>
```

Del lado de tu Backing bean vas a necesitar implementar el método `filtrarPorFecha`

```
public boolean filtrarPorFecha(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
//value es el que viene en la columna de tu datable
//filter es la fecha que ingresa el usuario para filtrar
//locale es opcional y lo podes usar o no segun el caso

//debes retornas true si el valor de la columna es aceptado por el filtro
//o false si no, o sea, si el filtro lo deja afuera       
}
```

Por otro lado, algunas recomendaciones.
Tus backing bean no debería tener lógica de negocio, sino de presentación. Y tené en cuenta que JSF es un framework orientado al servidor, muy pocas cosas se resuelven del lado del cliente. Las invocaciones al servicio rest que por lo visto invocas debería estar encapsulada en una capa de servicios. Y el backing bean debería invocar a este servicio para poder armar la pantalla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ha servido

Comment: Me alegro Iskandarina que te haya servido. Si puedes, marcala como útil, así a otras personas que tengan el mismo problema o misma duda que tu les puede ser útil.